# Unable to access a script from root directory in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a script in one of I my root directory:
/root/scripts/script1.sh

I wan't to call that script as another user (james1).

I did the following (as root user):

```
root@pc83$ CD scripts
root@pc83$ chown -R james1:user scripts
root@pc83$ CD scripts
root@pc83$ chmods 755 script1.sh
```

This made James 1 the owner of the script then I went to scripts directory and changed script1.sh permission to 755 which lets other execute.

Still when I connect as james1s and try to run script1. I can't.

```
james1@pc83$ /root/scripts/script.sh
```

I get permission denied error. Could some please let me know where I am going wrong? thanks.

I am using Oracle Enterprise Linux but tried to replicate the same problem in Ubuntu 10.10 and had the same issue.

Comment: "Root directory" usually means `/` and not `/root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `james1` have permission to execute the `root` folder? That's needed for directly accessing files under `/root/`.

Comment: Hi Graham, you mean chown the root folder?

Comment: no, you just need to `chmod`. Whatever field applies to `james1` (probably group or other) needs the `+x` bit.

Comment: No, he means does the current permission allow "other" to "execute"? Anyhow, put the script someplace like `/usr/local/bin` instead so you won't have to fiddle with permissions for `/root` - there's a reason they are somewhat tight.

Comment: @tripleee 
Not sure what Graham meant by the +x but it gave me an idea which I tried and worked. 

"$ chmod +x root" and then "$chmod 755 dummies -R" doing that I can now run scripts. Looks like all in between directories (in my case root and script) has to have o+x as well.

Comment: The "+x" is usually called the execute bit, but on a directory it has a special meaning "allow users to access specific items inside this directory". This is different from the "read" bit, which means "allow users to list this directory's contents" and is needed to do `ls`.